# Change the color of specific words in Microsoft Word/Publisher

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, colors, microsoft-publisher

I have a paragraph of text with 5 different colors. Is is possible to just change the color of black text to another color? If not, is there an easier way than just selecting each part of the text manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Document,

1. Press Ctrl-H
2. Click inside the 'find what' text box
3. Click 'more'
4. Click 'format' at the bottom
5. Select Font
6. Select the Characteristics of the text that you want to change and click 'ok'
7. Click inside the 'replace with' text box and repeat steps 3-5
8. Select the Characteristics of the text that you want the text to change to and click 'ok'
9. Now insert the Text you wish to replace the color of in the 'Find What' text box

If you wish to only replace the color, then there is no need to put any text in the 'replace with' text box.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl-F.
  type the text in 'find what' textbox.
  click find in .
  click main document.
  all matched text are slightly highlighted.

now go to home tab from the above blue ribbon.
  from the sub tab 'font' ,choose your font color.