# Replace word with different font and multiple colours

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a phrase in MS Word that I want to replace with a specific formatting. The formatting includes use of a specific font, and various colours throughout the word.

I know how to do an advanced search and replace as [shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/881678/change-the-color-of-specific-words-in-microsoft-word-publisher), but I'm unsure how to do it so that each letter in that word is that particular colour.

[image: Example]

Comment: Use the method shown in the link and change the letters one by one.

Comment: How would I specify which letter to replace in the word HELLO with the colour red, for example? Short of searching for every 'E' in the document

Comment: With a regular expression. [Regular expressions for finding text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295435.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not very exactly what you are looking for, but you could try to set up a gradient:

1. Select the text you want to format
2. Open the font color menu from the ribbon
3. Select Gradients > More Gradients
4. Select Gradient Fill in the panel appearing and configure it as you like.

#### Gradient

To make the gradient not as soft, make something like:

- 0% red
- 19% red
- 20% yellow
- 39% yellow
- 40% green
- ....

#### New Style

Then with the text still selected, create a new style:

1. Expand the style section
2. Click **Create a Style** and give it a name.

#### Search & Replace

Now you can use Ctrl+H to find and replace the text:

1. Enter the word you're searching for in both:

   - *Find what:*
   - *Replace with:*
2. In *Replace with* field, select Format (make sure you show **More >>**)
3. Select **Style** and select the style you just created with the additional ending *char*. (This makes sure it doesn't apply the style to the whole paragraph but only to the word.

Answer (score 0):

Format one HELLO with the colours, then select it and copy it (CTRL c).

Then in your find and replace, in the find type HELLO and select match case.

In replace, type ^c (that is for clipboard contents, which you have just copied your coloured HELLO to).